# What's the best way to manually save a webpage's html, so I can practice my parsing skills? (Right Clicking in Chrome isn't working)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am just getting started on my first web scraping project.

Before I go and install a headless browser etc, I thought I would just save the page manually and work on parsing the dom, as a mini project.

Well, Trying to just save the page with right-clicking and saving the file as -> HTML only.... is not resulting in an HTML file with any of the information I am looking to parse.

I see the information I want in HTML tags, when I open the console. How can I get the HTML with the information in an external file, so that I can play with loading it into my js script?

Also curious why it is that right-clicking in chrome -> save as -> Html ONLY, is producing such different than expected results?

This is the page, I am trying to parse:
[link](https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/venta/medellin?utm_source=google&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=marca_antioquia_febrero_2022_sem&utm_campaign=MARCA_2018&utm_term=search_ad_marca&utm_term=finca+raiz+medellin&utm_content=antioquia_medellin_na&hsa_acc=7897484587&hsa_cam=1469176255&hsa_grp=56583696603&hsa_ad=280714107727&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-298777225823&hsa_kw=finca+raiz+medellin&hsa_mt=b&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=Cj0KCQjwg_iTBhDrARIsAD3Ib5jIbfI1gCncS3GdDXnmvhnzwqv4G6Hdv6fpLFFV_wHlbA3jJBbsQ3EaAoZKEALw_wcB&pagina=1)
I am just trying to pull out all the prices associated with real estate, which are in the console obviously, but not in my downloaded HTML files....

Thanks!
First ever stack overflow post,
--Noob.

.....

Comment: try ctrl-a then right click and save selection source - chances are you're trying to save a dynamically created page, so the regular right click -> save just saves the actual HTML loaded

Answer (score 0):

F12 -> elements panel -> right click on html element and copy / copy outerHTML

Comment: Thanks, this is my first ever post, simple solution :) YAY HERE WE GO :)